# How to retrieve the list of "people you may know" using facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to retrieve the list of "people you may know" using facebook API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, at this stage, there is no way to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can people you may know sort of algorithm by yourself,It basically works on similarities between users e.g mutual friends, schools,common location,likes etc.
I am also trying to create an algorithm like this.
let me know if you get any success.